# django-pgcrypto-fields taking long time to load

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-authentication, pgcrypto

I'm using `django 2.2.13` and `django-pgcrypto-fields 2.5.2`. Also i'm using `email` as authentication method. `email` is stored as `pgcrypto` field. There are around 10000 active users. When user tries to login it takes a long time (8-9 seconds). I tried to login from shell, it also takes a long time.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(email='john@gmail.com', password='secret')
```

The authenticate function takes almost 7-8 seconds to execute.

```
user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
```

When I try to authenticate using `username`, it executes within 1 seconds

```
from app.models import User
user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
```

The above query also takes a long time to execute (7-8 seconds). I tried indexing the email column, but the outcome is same. How can I speed up authentication and filter queries for pgcrypto fields?

Answer (score 0):

I have got a workaround solution. I have narrowed down user list by `last_login` and override `_authenticate_by_email` method of `django-allauth`

```
class CustomAuthenticationBackend(AuthenticationBackend):
    def _authenticate_by_email(self, **credentials):
        email = credentials.get('email', credentials.get('username'))
        if email:
            startdate= timezone.now() - timedelta(days=CACHED_AUTHENTICATION_DAY)
            user = User.objects.filter(last_login__gte=startdate, email=email).first()
            if user:
                if self._check_password(user, credentials["password"]):
                    return user
                return None
            for user in filter_users_by_email(email):
                if self._check_password(user, credentials["password"]):
                    return user
        return None
```

So if the `CACHED_AUTHENTICATION_DAY` is set to 30/60 days, then active users will be able to login very fast.